# google maps javascript directionsService.route request inside class: pass the class instance to the callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The google maps directions service route request has the following prototype:

```
route(request:DirectionsRequest, callback:function(DirectionsResult, DirectionsStatus))
```

I'm invoking the service request inside a class instance method that looks something like this:

```
myClass.protype.routeStuff(){
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
         '''handle the response here'''
        });
};
```

I need to access the myClass instance in '''handle the response here'''.  I'm not a JS expert. How can I pass it along?

More generally, given the prototype for route, how can I pass additional arguments to the callback function?

Update 1:
I ended up using Chad's answer creating a class call back method invoked thus:

```
directionsService.route(request, this.extendRouteToLocationCallback.bind(this));
```

Independently I was able to resolve the problem by forcing a closure on the callback function like this:

```
var extrastuff = this;
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    routeCallback(extrastuff, response, status);});
```

I believe it is also possible to do this:

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    routeCallback(response, status);}.bind(this));
```

For my immediate purposes Chad's approach yields somewhat better structured code.

Update 2: The final solution I adopted bound to this and passed extra arguments like this:

```
var request = buildMapRequest(currentEndLocation, null, location);
directionsService.route(request, this.extendRouteToLocationCallback.bind(this, location));
```

And the callback looked like this:

```
Route.prototype.extendRouteToLocationCallback = function(location, response, status){...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Function binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
function directionsServiceCallback(response, status){
   // this keyword is now a reference to a myClass instance due to
   // function binding.
});

myClass.protype.routeStuff(){
  directionsService.route(request, directionsServiceCallback.bind(this));
};
```